# Need to remove borders from multiple images

Tags: windows, command-line, images, batch, processing

I have a few hundred family images and they were all sent to us with borders that I would like to remove. Thankfully the borders are all the same size of 20 pixels and they are all .jpg so this will probably make things easier but im looking for a way to "batch process" all of them quickly so I dont need to open photoshop for each image and do it individually. Command line is preferred, the only big problem is they are mostly different sizes.

Comment: This question has a broken image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for this. You will need to use the `-shave` switch.

example:

```
convert -shave 20x20 *.jpg
```